# Accessing same instance of Javascript class from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this JavaScript class "Test". I want to make instance of it in Main react component and then later use the same instance in another react component called by some action.

```
class Test
    {
        constructor( arg1, arg2 )
        {
            console.log("initialize with " + arg1 + arg2);
    }
        
        method1(input) {
            console.log("Using this in Main component")
        }

        method2(input) {
            console.log("I want to use this in another component but with same instance as Main component is using.")
        }
    
    }
    export default Test;
```

This is beginning of my Main component where I am creating instance of Test

```
class Main extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        new Test("arg1", "arg2")
            .then(test => {
                test.method1("input");
            });
    }
```

Now I want to use the same instance of Test which I made above in below but this time use `method2`.

```
    export default class AccessFromhere extends React.Component {
        constructor()
        {
            super();
            this.access = this.access.bind(this);
        }
        access()
        {
            console.log("How to get same instance of Test from here to use method2 instead.")
  new Test("arg1", "arg2")
                .then(test => {
                    test.method2("input");
                });
        }
```

I did it with creating new instance of Test but it felt like not a good way to do this.

Comment: You'll need to have the original instance passed as an argument to the function where you want to use it again or you will have to declare the instance variable in a high enough scope that is accessible by any other code that wants to use it.

Comment: You're probably looking for a singleton: http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you export `Test` from the first file, do it as follows:

```
export default new Test("arg1", "arg2");
```

From there on, whenever you import `Test`, you'll be actually getting the same instance you created in the export statement. Just remove the `new` statements from wherever you were creating a `Test` object before and instead just use the imported instance.

This is a simplified form of the [Singleton design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern) which is possible using ES6 imports.